# How can I catch focus event on nested nodes of contenteditable div in vue?

Tags: vue.js

I have this template in vue:

```
<div contenteditable>
    <p>First paragraph</p>
    <p>Second paragraph</p>
</div>
```

I can catch focus on root div but I don't see any action if I add focus event handler to paragraph tag like this:

```
...
<p @focus="handleFocus">First paragraph</p>
...
```

How can I do that? Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `tabindex="0"`

```
<p @focus="handleFocus" tabindex="0">First paragraph</p>
```

I recon p-tag isn't a focus able tag so you got to define it to be focus able. Not entirely sure about the explanation but it works. Hope I helped

Comment: It looks like `tabindex`  is what I need. Also I have set `tabindex="-1"` and it works for me. Thank you!